# WPF WebBrowser - How to Zoom Content?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, expression-blend

Trying to test basic browser concepts in a WPF (C#/XAML, .NET 4.0) WebBrowser application. So far, the only problem is programatically zooming. Has anyone had any experience with this?

MSDN lists nothing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx
Additionally, I have tried various things such as RenderTransform options to no avail. Either this is not possible or not documented. I'm hoping for the latter. Note that a WinForm solution isn't acceptable.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Beems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you can execute a javascript like this.

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;
```

In WPF we can manipulate the document. I Created a Extension Method for you, so you can set the Zoom:

```
// www.tonysistemas.com.br
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SetZoom(this System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser WebBrowser1, double Zoom)
    {
        // For this code to work: add the Microsoft.mshtml .NET reference      
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = WebBrowser1.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
        doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.body.style.zoom=" + Zoom.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ";");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WebBrowser1.SetZoom(0.5);
```

Comment: Tony, thank you for the response. What do I need to add to my project? I'm getting the following error: "The type or namespace name 'mshtml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: For this code to work: add the Microsoft.mshtml .NET reference

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to get that to recognize as a valid namespace. ("using Microsoft.mshtml.net").

Comment: You need to right-click on the Project References and select menu Add Reference

Comment: This only zooms the page not the content.  The end result of this effect is that the content that is in the right/bottom portion of the screen will be pushed off of the viewable area to the right/bottom for zooming in or making the zoom > 100% or greater than 1.0 in this example.

Comment: Instead of zoom, try transform to keep the contents from being pushed to the bottom right: doc.parentWindow.execScript($"document.body.style.transform='scale({Zoom})';");

Comment: I'm trying to set the zoom when the window first loads. This only works sometimes, and I can't figure out why. Sometimes when I debug I get a Script Error window that says "Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null object reference." That window doesn't look like it's generated by Visual Studio. But then after I click Yes or No I can see in Visual Studio that the execScript() line threw a COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'

Comment: Okay, I've fixed that problem by handling the WebBrowser's LoadCompleted event. However, now when I try to set the zoom the WebBrowser just shows a "To help protect your security, your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options..." warning at the top and doesn't set the zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I used bits and pieces from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326179/17822 to assist with the zoom issue.   The key here is the ExecWB method.  The zoom on the Windows Desktop is not 1-1 to the zoom on the WebBrowser Control.  You will have to play with it.  The pseudo-code for the equation looks like this:

```
zoomLevel = (winDesktopZoom - 100) + _winDesktopZoom + 10
```

Note that you will need a reference to SHDocVw.dll which can be found in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 for x64 machines and in C:\Windows\System32 for x86 machines.

This is not pretty, but it is the only thing that I have found, short of upgrading to http://awesomium.com that actually matches IE default zoom settings (which default to the Windows Desktop zoom) to WebBrowser Control.  Also note that the Windows Desktop Zoom only exists for Vista, Win 7 and probably 2k8 as well in the Control Panel --> Display, but I didn't check Vista or 2k8.  It is not there for XP (any service pack).

To get the Windows Desktop Zoom (this does work on XP for some reason) I did:

```
var presentSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);

if (presentSource != null && presentSource.CompositionTarget != null 
    && presentSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice != null)
{
    _zoomPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(100 * presentSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11);
}
```

This logic is placed in the OnSourceInitialized override for that XAML Window.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this:

http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/a-real-net-4-0-webbrowser/