# WPF WebBrowser control zoom in/out support?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, zooming

For a WPF WebBrowser control, is there a way to duplicate Internet Explorer's zoom functionality?

In other words, Internet Explorer has the menu View > Zoom > 75%, which renders the web page at 75% scale.  Is there a way to make a web browser control, which is embedded in a WPF app, do the same thing?

I've seen this post:
[WPF WebBrowser - How to Zoom Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122485/wpf-webbrowser-how-to-zoom-content)

But it only seems to scale the page and not the page content.

Answer (score 7):

```
public partial class TestWindow: UserControl
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        browser.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(browser_LoadCompleted);
    }

    private void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            FieldInfo webBrowserInfo = browser.GetType().GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            object comWebBrowser = null;
            object zoomPercent = 120;
            if (webBrowserInfo != null)
                comWebBrowser = webBrowserInfo.GetValue(browser);
            if (comWebBrowser != null)
            {
                InternetExplorer ie = (InternetExplorer)comWebBrowser;
                ie.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref zoomPercent, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }


    public void SetBrowser(string url)
    {
        browser.Navigate(url,null,null,null);

    }

    internal void Destroy()
    {
        try
        {
            if (browser.Parent != null)
            {
                ((Grid)browser.Parent).Children.Remove(browser);
                browser.Navigate("about:blank");
                browser.Dispose();
                browser = null;
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }

}
```

Comment: this one saved me :) u need to add You need to add a reference to a COM component called Microsoft Internet Controls.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it:

```
// Needed to expose the WebBrowser's underlying ActiveX control for zoom functionality
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
internal interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
}

static readonly Guid SID_SWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

private void ZoomListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object zoomPercent; // A VT_I4 percentage ranging from 10% to 1000%
    switch(ZoomListBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: 200%":
            zoomPercent = 200;
            break;
        case "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: 100%":
            zoomPercent = 100;
            break;
        case "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: 50%":
            zoomPercent = 50;
            break;
        default:
            zoomPercent = 100;
            break;
    }

    // grab a handle to the underlying ActiveX object
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;
    if (m_webView.Document != null)
    {
        serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)m_webView.Document;
    }

    Guid serviceGuid = SID_SWebBrowserApp;
    Guid iid = typeof(SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2).GUID;
    SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 browserInst = (SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref iid);

    // send the zoom command to the ActiveX object
    browserInst.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref zoomPercent, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

All the service provider stuff exposes the ActiveX since the WPF WebBrowser control doesn't expose it directly. Aside from that, it's pretty much the same as alexei's solution.

Comment: I took bits and pieces from this answer to solve my problem.  This works very nicely.  The odd thing is that the IE zoom level, which defaults to the Windows Desktop Control Panel --> Display on Win 7 is not 1-1, so you have to use an equation like this to get it to work.  See this answer on a different/but similar post for how I did it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11528480/17822

Answer (score 2):

This is not an exact answer since it is for the WinForms control, but perhaps will be useful in case you decide to use it in a WindowsFormsHost instead of the WPF control, which exposes way too little to be useful.

You could use an OLE commands through ExecWB on the ActiveX instance: `OLECMDID_ZOOM` for text size and `OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM` for optical zoom. For example,

```
object pvaIn = 200; // A VT_I4 percentage ranging from 10% to 1000%
var browserInst = ((SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)(browserContol.ActiveXInstance));
browserInst.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM,
                   SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,
                   ref pvaIn, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Some notes:

- a reference to Interop.SHDocVw assembly is needed
- the command succeeds only after a document has loaded
- the range of pvaIn could be retrieved via `OLECMDID_GETZOOMRANGE`
- for reference list of commands is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- I experienced this strange behavior that seemed to happen only on non-96 dpi. Upon startup, the rendered text size did not correspond to that stored in OLECMDID_ZOOM state. Setting the value (to any value) did not fix the discrepancy: the rendered size is still what looked like [stored size + 2]. When optical zoom was set to 100%, the discrepancy in text-size went away (text size visibly shrank after zooming to 100%). This did't happen in IE, and perhaps that was just a weird artifact in my environment -- but just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

When using the other solutions, I always get errors of kind

> HRESULT: 0x80040100
>   DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED

I found a solution on [this page](http://www.progtown.com/topic42679-axshdocvw-axwebbrowser-olecmdidopticalzoom.html) that worked for me:

```
var wb = webBrowser.ActiveXInstance.GetType();

object o = zoomPercentage; // Between 10 and 1000.

wb.InvokeMember(
    @"ExecWB", 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
    null, 
    webBrowser.ActiveXInstance, 
    new[]
        {
            OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, 
            OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 
            o, 
            o
        });
```

With `OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM` being 63 and `OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER` being 2.