# WPF WebBrowser - Is it possible to set device-width?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, width

I've run into this quite annoying problem, where I have a WebBrowser control on a WPF window, and it should show the content of a responsive website.

Even though the WebBrowser control is only 360px wide, and the website's CSS changes the layout at 540px or below, it still shows the content as if it was over 540px wide.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control in WPF uses the same engine as Internet Explorer. Does it work in Internet Explorer? If not, you might want to try fixing it so that it is IE friendly and try again.

Comment: Yes, it works just fine in IE. It's like the website doesn't get any information about the window size.

Answer (score 0):

you  can try the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122485/wpf-webbrowser-how-to-zoom-content) and set  the zoom  to 0.80 something like this  is the only work around that come in my mind now

```
WebBrowser1.SetZoom(0.8);
```