# Artificially increasing size of .NET WebBrowser? (WinForms or WPF)

Tags: c#, size, resolution, pixel, dpi

I am wondering if there is a way to artificially increase the size of a control (more specifically, a web browser) in .NET C#, or any language for that matter. By artificially increase, I mean, make every pixel take up the space of 4, effectively making the control 2 times larger.

I would like to make not only the webBrowser be twice as large, but all the content on it as well. Such that a 200x200 image on a website would appear to be 400x400, to the eye of the user.

I was able to achieve this effect by simply forcing a screen resolution change, which made the control appear bigger, **but** this is not the way I want to do it.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Drawing to a canvas or picture box is not an option, as it would be too slow..

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: if you're using WPF, it's as simple as `LayoutTransform`/`RenderTransform`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122485/wpf-webbrowser-how-to-zoom-content