# Application with WebBrowser and high-resolution display

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I develop WPF application and use embedded WebBrowser control to show some HTML content.

This works fine. But content is too small on high-resolution display.

How can I scale content only for high-resolution displays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this response to apply zoom: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5123734/18452174

Maybe interesting this event to change zoom if resolution is changed:

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += OnDisplaySettingsChanged;

private void OnDisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Set zoom based on resolution
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I hope you have placed your web page in any of these controls. They actually don't resize your content and will not display on high definition display.

```
StackPanel
WrapPanel
Canvas
TabControl
```

Please place your content in any of these controls. These controls will resize the web page or content when it is maximized.

```
Grid
UniformGrid
DockPanel
```