# WPF Webbrowser How do I zoom out on Page loaded event?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

This Event handler returns:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))'

Code:

```
private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        browser.InvokeScript("Document.Body.Style =" + "zoom:80%");
    }
```

i have tried many solutions found online, but none seem to work for me
please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var zoom = 0.8;
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = browser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
        doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.body.style.zoom=" + zoom.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ";");
    }
```

Its working for me.

*Don't forget to reference Microsoft.mshtml*

References:

- [WPF WebBrowser - How to Zoom Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122485/wpf-webbrowser-how-to-zoom-content)
- [Zoom WPF-WebBrowser-Control Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871274/zoom-wpf-webbrowser-control-content)